# Handling NULL in a stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a stored procedure that accepts a parameter called `@Vendor`. I want the query to work this way depending on the value of `@Vendor`.

1. `IF @Vendor IS NOT NULL` --> Filter on `Vendorname = @Vendor`
2. `IF @Vendor IS NULL` --> do not apply `Vendorname` filter in `WHERE` clause

The strategy I have in mind is to apply an IF branch to execute two versions of the same query, one with the `Vendorname WHERE` clause filter and one without.

```
IF (@Vendor IS NOT NULL) {
    select *
    from table
    where Vendorname = @Vendor;
} ELSE {
    select *
    from table;
}
```

That syntax may be slightly incorrect, but I believe the general approach should work.

However, my question is whether there's a more concise way to do this, as opposed to copying the same SQL statement over again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write the logic as:

```
select *
from table
where (Vendorname = @Vendor) OR (@Vendor IS NULL)
```

One caution:  This may not be as optimized as your version, if you have an index on `Vendorname`.

Comment: Simple and good answer. But I always like to put all conditions for an OR inside brackets. Just in case for when you put an AND condition in later and you forget the brackets, then your result may be not what you expected

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from table
where Vendorname = case when @Vendor is not null then @Vendor else Vendorname end;
```

Comment: Careful: this fails if there are any rows where `Vendorname` is `NULL`, if the intent is to include those rows when `@Vendor` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Using an IF is the right choice here. Using "catch all" parameters can lead to poor choices by the query planner.

SQL doesn't use Brackets ({ }), it uses BEGIN and END. Thus you get:

```
IF @Vendor IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SELECT*
    FROM table
    WHERE Vendorname = @Vendor;
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM table;
END
```

Comment: Creating multiple execution paths can also lead to inefficient execution plans. And really the BEGIN/END is not needed here as the contents are single statements.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you can use :

```
select * from table
where isnull(Vendorname, '') = coalesce(@Vendor, Vendorname, '')
```

Comment: Using `coalesce()`you could avoid nested `isnull()` operators (and create more universal code).

Comment: @Arvo - Can you please give an example to avoid the nested `isnull()` in the above query?

Comment: `coalesce(Vendorname, '') = coalesce(@Vendor, Vendorname, '')`

Comment: This precludes any use of indexes, even with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. Use only if performance is no concern.